# How does modifying a directory affect its Parent Directory timestamp in Linux?

Tags: linux, timestamp, stat

For example, if I create a directory, check its timestamp, then create a directory inside the first directory a minute later, the timestamp for the mtime will change to when the new directory was created. However if I wait another minute and create a third directory inside the second, the second directory will update the mtime to the third directory's time while the first directory will still have the 2nd directory's original mtime. Despite the contents of the first directory changing when the third directory is created, the mtime doesn't change.

Is there documentation as to how linux looks to change mtime? Or is it only able to see direct children changes to update mtime?

Comment: Read up on "inodes" and it'll make more sense. Here's [an article](http://www.linux.org/threads/intro-to-inodes.4130/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I could find. From the `stat` man page:

> The field st_mtime is changed by file modifications, for example, by
>   mknod(2), truncate(2), utime(2) and write(2) (of more than zero
>   bytes). Moreover, st_mtime of a directory is changed by the creation
>   or deletion of files in that directory. The st_mtime field is not
>   changed for changes in owner, group, hard link count, or mode.
>   -[Source](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

This wording implies to me that a modification in mtime of a nested directory is not considered a modification by the parent directory, since it does not qualify as a `mknod`, `truncate`, `utime`, or `write` operation.

Hope this helps!